# Unable to start mysql in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have tried the following the code to restart the MySql services

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

got the following error

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-52-10:~$ journalctl -xe

And the journalctl Log says

```
    Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Mar 17 15:10:55 ip-172-31-52-10 audit[4057]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=4057 comm="mysqld" r
Mar 17 15:10:55 ip-172-31-52-10 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1552835455.957:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/syst
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 mysql-systemd-start[4038]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 mysql-systemd-start[4038]: 2019-03-17T15:10:56.000286Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'bind=0.0.0.0'
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 mysql-systemd-start[4038]: 2019-03-17T15:10:56.004319Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 mysql-systemd-start[4038]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 mysql-systemd-start[4038]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 17 15:10:56 ip-172-31-52-10 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like `apparmor` prevents access to the binary.

Comment: can you please help me fix this

Comment: Hmm how did you install mysql? Could you list the contents of the folder `/etc/apparmor.d/`?

Comment: here is the content
https://imgur.com/PaSYOr6

Comment: Hm, looks fine, and the contents of `usr.sbin.mysqld`?

Comment: here it is https://pastebin.com/tMvaSkLh

Comment: Seems you are not alone: https://askubuntu.com/questions/916009/mysql-wont-start-because-of-apparmor --- https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004185293-Unable-to-start-MySQL-on-Ubuntu-AVC-apparmor-DENIED-operation-open- --- https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql But it looks like you can fix that ;-)

Comment: tried them already didn't work

Comment: Oh! Hmm I vaguely remember similar issues, but with the embedded version of mysql in my akonadi PIM service. I also had to create an apparmor profile and grant permissions. Have you tried launching the service without apparmor? Does that work?

Comment: tried them already didn't work planning to reinstall if am unable to fix it

Comment: Reinstalling never fixes things on a Linux system.

Comment: I think you can use ´sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld´ to prevent apparmor from blocking the access to that binary and only complain in the log instead. What happens if you do that?

Comment: sudo: aa-complain: command not found

Comment: Unless you have not tinkered around with your `PATH` environment variable I would suggest you install package `apparmor-utils`... (`sudo apt install apparmor-utils`)

Comment: will give it a try now

Comment: finally, reinstalling did the job perhaps it seems a bug which often occurs based on the user action.

Comment: Not by interactions with the database server. Only if you fiddled around with the system setup which you never mentioned...